# Adjacency Matrix for Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am studying graphs and came across this questions. I was wondering if anyone would be able to help assist me.

If G is a graph with an adjacency matrix $A=A(G)$, what is the interpretation of the $i,j$ entry of $A'$?

Comment: Judging by the answer you accepted, the $A^{\prime}$ is a typo and you are only asking about the $ij$ entry of $A$, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_{ij} = 1$ if there is an edge between nodes $i$ and $j$, and $A_{ij}=0$ otherwise. For an undirected graph, an edge between nodes $i$ and $j$ is the same as an edge between nodes $j$ and $i$, so $A_{ij} = A_{ji}$ (i.e. the adjacency matrix is symmetric).

For a directed graph, $A_{ij}=1$ if there is an edge from $i$ to $j$, and $A_{ij}=0$ otherwise.

For a weighted graph, the value $1$ will be replaced with the weight (in the appropriate sense for directed/undirected graphs).